# FrameLabel is Broken for ArrayPlot and MatrixPlot

Tags: plotting, bugs, labeling

In version 11.0.1 the documentation for `FrameLabel` states its format is

> {{*left*, *right*}, {*bottom*, *top*}}

However, it appears that this is not the case for `MatrixPlot`.

```
MatrixPlot[IdentityMatrix[4], FrameLabel -> {{"left", "right"}, {"bottom", "top"}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Nor for `ArrayPlot`.

```
ArrayPlot[IdentityMatrix[4], FrameLabel -> {{"left", "right"}, {"bottom", "top"}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It appears that somehow the format is getting a `RotateLeft` inside these functions before it is being used.  `RotateRight` does provide a workaround.

```
MatrixPlot[IdentityMatrix[4], FrameLabel -> RotateRight@{{"left", "right"}, {"bottom", "top"}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Can anyone else confirm this behaviour? Looks like a bug to me.
Win 7 Pro Mma 11.0.1

Confirmed bug: Have to figure out the case number as I am getting a couple of confirms at the moment but all on the same case number. It is one of these but three where responded with separate emails all from one case number so I can't tell which one it is. [CASE:3780234] [CASE:3780235] [CASE:3780239]

Comment: I get the same behavior with `Graphics[
 {
  Rectangle[]
  },
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {{"left", "right"}, {"bottom", "top"}}
 ]` coming out with the expected orientation.

Comment: Same issue in version 9.0 (windows 10).

Comment: Same behavior for `11.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 20, 2016)`.  `% // InputForm` returns a `Graphics` object with `FrameLabel -> {{"bottom", "top"}, {"left", "right"}}`.  I would call this a bug and suggest that it be so labeled.

Comment: Same behavior in version 6 for Windows.

Comment: Reporting to WRI to see what they say.